# Eigenvalues of a (non-traditional) Kronecker sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, kronecker-product

I am trying to find some properties about the eigenvalues of the following Kronecker sum

$$ M = (\mathbb{I}_{\nu} \otimes A) + (B \otimes \mathbb{I}_{\nu})$$

where  $A, B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $\mathbb{I}_{\nu}$ denotes the $\nu \times \nu$ identity matrix and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.

I am interested in the location of the eigenvalues of $M$, since I need some conditions to guarantee the existence of the inverse. In this case, the well-known result about the *Kronecker sum* would only apply if $\nu = n$.

In fact, in my case, this last statement does not hold, and I'm interested in a more general situation where $\nu \neq n$.

Comment: Probably you meant $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and not $W$!

Comment: @DavideMorgante thanks a million! I'll change it right away.

Comment: If $A, B$ were positive definite, you would be able to conclude that $M$ is invertible, right?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1836537/339790