# How to compute the determinant of a block circulant matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices, circulant-matrices

I am curious if there are any general formulas for problems like this or special cases. I want to compute the determinant of $2n \times 2n$ complex matrices made of identical $2 \times 2$ matrices. If there are no generalities then any insight into the topic is appreciated.

For example, I built a matrix out of $2 \times 2$ matrices. Let

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \newline b & a \end{bmatrix}, \qquad B= \begin{bmatrix} c & 0 \newline 0 & c \end{bmatrix} $$

What is the determinant of the following matrix?

$$ C = \begin{bmatrix}
A & B & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \newline
0 & A & B & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \newline
0 & 0 & A & B & 0 & \dots & 0 \newline
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \newline
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & A  & B & 0 \newline
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & A  & B \newline
B & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

Of course, $0$ symbolizes now the $2 \times 2$ zero matrix. What changes if we have zero instead of $B$ in the left bottom corner?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: Let $P$ be the $2N\times 2N$ block matrix consists of  $N$ copies of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & -1\\1 & 1\end{smallmatrix}]$  along the diagonal. The even and odd row/columns of $PCP^{-1}$ are [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's address the easy part first: if the lower-left entry is a $0$ instead of $B$, then $C$ is block upper-triangular, which means that its determinant is given by the product of the determinants of the diagonal blocks. That is, we would find
$$
\det(C) = \det(A)^n = (a^2 - b^2)^n.
$$
In light of my below discussion of the original matrix: the eigenvalues of $A$ are of the form $a \pm b$. Correspondingly, $C$ has the same eigenvalues, but each with multiplicity $n$.

---

The matrix $C$ (as originally presented) can be written nicely in terms of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). In particular, let $J$ and $P$ denote the matrices (of sizes $2 \times 2$ and $n \times n$ respectively)
$$
J = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad P = \pmatrix{0&1\\&0&1\\&&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&&0&1\\
1&&&&0},
$$
and let $I_k$ denote the identity matrix of size $k$. Then
$$
C = aI + b(I_n \otimes J) + c(P \otimes I_2).
$$
The eigenvalues of $J$ are $\pm 1$, and the eigenvalues of $P$ are the $n$th roots of unity (i.e. $e^{2\pi ki/n}$ for $k = 0,\dots,n-1$).

The properties of the Kronecker product allow us to deduce that for matrices $X,Y$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m$ and $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n$ respectively, it [can be shown that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1836537/81360) the eigenvalues of $I_n\otimes X + Y\otimes I_m$ are given by $\mu_j + \lambda_k$ for all pairs $j,k$ with $1 \leq j \leq m$ and $1 \leq k \leq n$. Applying this to $X = bJ$ and $y = cP$ allows us to see that the eigenvalues of $C - aI$ are given by
$$
(-1)^jb + e^{2\pi k i/n} c, \quad 0 \leq j \leq 1, \quad 0 \leq k \leq n-1.
$$
Thus, the eigenvalues of $C$ have the form
$$
a + (-1)^jb + e^{2\pi k i/n} c, \quad 0 \leq j \leq 1, \quad 0 \leq k \leq n-1.
$$
The determinant of $C$ is the product of its eigenvalues.

---

If $a,b,c$ are real, it is notable that the eigenvalues of $C$ can be put into complex conjugate pairs. For $k = 0,1,\dots,\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor$, we find that
$$
(a + (-1)^jb + e^{2\pi k i/n} c)(a + (-1)^jb + e^{2\pi (n-k) i/n} c) = \\
|a + (-1)^jb + e^{2\pi k i/n} c|^2 = \\
[(a + (-1)^jb) + c\cos(2\pi k/n)]^2 + c\sin^2(2\pi k/n).
$$
With that, the determinant of $C$ can be written as the product of real numbers.